# Can a generalization of the Hermite function-like "basis" $φ_n(x) = D^n \exp(-x^2/2)$ be orthonormal in $L^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality, hermite-polynomials

I'm trying to find an orthonormal basis with respect to a weight function $w(x) \equiv 1$ 
for $L^2$ in terms of the following proposed basis functions:
$$ φ_n(x) = D^n \exp(-x^2/2),\quad n=0,1,2,\ldots \tag{1}$$
where $D^n$ is the derivative operator.

Unfortunately, it seems that this cannot be done. Define
$$
M_{mn}=\frac{1}{Z_{mn}}\int φ_m(x) φ_n(x) dx
$$
where $Z_{mn}=\sqrt{\pi}\ 2^{-(m+n)/2}\ (m+n-1)!!$.

Then, for example, for the first five basis functions we have the following singular matrix:
$$
M_{mn}=\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
 -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

As far as my manipulations have been correct it seems to me that Eq. (1) cannot be written in terms of Hermite functions. **Question 1: Is this true?** Does the singularity of $M_{mn}$ indicate that (linear combinations of) the functions (1) can never form a basis, and thus that they cannot be equivalent to Hermite functions?

---

I suspect an orthonormal basis in form similar to Eq. (1) might still be possible with a generalization. Rewrite Eq. (1) as
$$
φ_n(x)=\sqrt{2π}\ D^n φ(x); \tag{1'}
$$
i.e. $φ(x)=\exp(-x^2/2)/\sqrt{2π}$.
Now for each $n$ we perform a custom translation and (positive) rescaling of the Gaussian $φ(x)$:
$$
Φ_n(x;μ_n,σ_n) = a_n(μ_n,σ_n)\ D^n \left[\frac{1}{σ_n}φ\left(\frac{x-μ_n}{σ_n}\right)\right]. \quad n=0,1,2,\ldots \tag{2}
$$
**Question 2: For which $(a_n,μ_n,σ_n)$, if any, would Eq. (2) represent an orthonormal basis for $(L^2,w(x)\equiv 1)$?** Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That the Hermite functions are orthogonal follow from that $f(x,t) = e^{-t^2/2+2xt-x^2} $ satisfies $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,t)f(x,u)dx= g(tu)$ thus with $f(x,t)=\sum_n t^n H_n(x), g( v)=\sum_k c_k v^k $ we have $\sum_{n,m} t^n u^m \int_{-\infty}^\infty H_n(x)H_m(x)dx= \sum_k c_k (tu)^k$. Those kind of generating functions are very rare.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That derivation is most elegant.